# reactive forms in angular with disabled form control value cannot be changed dynamically

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular11

I Have a Reactive form with form control that has the disabled attribute, but when I try to change its value using patch value it ends with 'undefined'.

this is the form and I change the end date automatically when a user enters a start date and duration so I need it disabled:

```
 this.newProcessForm = new FormGroup({
  'start_date':new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  'end_date':new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
  'ex_duration':new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
})
```

this is where i change the value :

```
const newEndDate = this.dCalc.SubTaskEndDateCalculation(this.newProcess).toLocaleDateString();
this.newProcessForm.patchValue({
  'end_date' : newEndDate
})
```

*and it appears on the template correctly but when I submit the form the value of this field returns undefined like this img [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weFdr.png)*

Answer (score 0):

It Worked By using the read-only attribute in the template and remove the disabled from form control.

so the code is

```
this.newProcessForm = new FormGroup({
  'start_date':new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  'end_date':new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  'ex_duration':new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
})
```

and in the template the mat-input

```
<input type="text" matInput id="end_date" formControlName="end_date" readonly>
```